# Approximating piecewise linear function

Tags: calculus, approximation, approximation-theory

I'm trying to derive an analytic approximation to the following piecewise linear function:

$$ f(x) = \left\{
\begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{x}{x_s} &   & \text{if} &  x < x_s \\ 
\frac{1-x}{1-x_s} &  & \text{if} & x \geq x_s
\end{eqnarray} \right.
$$

where (and this is an **edit**), $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0<x_s<1$. I've been trying some approximating functions like $\tilde{f}(x) = x (1-x) g(x)$, assuming that $\tilde{f}'(x_s) = 0$ and $\tilde{f}(x_s) = 1$ and solving for $g(x;A,B) = A (x-x_s) + B$ but what I obtained was not very helpful...

Does anybody know any kind of analytical approximation for $f(x)$ in terms of, for example, hyperbolic trigonometric functions or exponentials?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As written, the function is not defined for $x\ge x_s$ if we happen to have $x_s=1$.

Comment: $\frac12\left(\frac1{x_s}-\frac1{1-x_s}\right)-f(x-x_s)$ is a multiple of $x\mapsto |x|$ and not nicely approximated by analytic functions.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that $x_s \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Is the question still open?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm using an equilateral hyoerbola to approximate the function, but any other suggestions will be gladly welcomed.

Comment: @Dmoreno: See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a **convolution** with *a function of small width and great height*
(: Richard P. Feynman in 'Space-Time Approach to Quantum Electrodynamics').
Name this function $\delta(x)$ (not quite by coincidence).
The simplest one is $\,\delta(x) = B(x/\sigma)/\sigma\,$ where $\sigma \rightarrow 0$ and:
$$
B(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
0 & \mbox{for} & t \le -1/2 \\
1 & \mbox{for} & -1/2 \le t \le +1/2 \\
0 & \mbox{for} & +1/2 \le t
\end{array} \right.
$$
The geometry of $\,\delta(x)\,$ is a rectangle with height $1/\sigma$ and width $\sigma$ ,
resulting in an area $1$, thus establishing that the function $\,\delta(x)\,$ is normed.
Now define:
$$ \overline{f}(x) = 
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x-t)\,f(t)\,dt
= \frac{1}{\sigma} \int_{x-\sigma/2}^{x+\sigma/2} f(t)\,dt
$$
This is what we find:
$$
\overline{f}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
x/x_s & \mbox{for} & x \le x_s-\sigma/2 \\
P(x) & \mbox{for} & x_s-\sigma/2 \le x \le  x_s+\sigma/2 \\
(1-x)/(1-x_s) & \mbox{for} & x_s+\sigma/2 < x
\end{array} \right.
$$
Where the (piece of a) parabola $\,P(x)\,$ is defined as:
$$ P(x) =
\frac{1}{\sigma}\int_{x-\sigma/2}^{x_s} \frac{t}{x_s}\,dt +
\frac{1}{\sigma}\int_{x_s}^{x+\sigma/2} \frac{1-t}{1-x_s}\,dt = \\
\frac {4\,{{\it x_s}}^{2}+4\,{x}^{2}-4\,x\sigma+8\,x\sigma\,{
\it x_s}+{\sigma}^{2}-8\,{\it x_s}\,x-4\,\sigma\,{\it x_s}}{8\sigma
\,{\it x_s}\, \left( -1+{\it x_s} \right) }
$$
Thus, with the simplest convolution kernel, the result is a piecewise analytic
function. The original $\,f(x)\,$ is in black, the convoluted one 
$\,\overline{f}(x)\,$ is in $\color{red}{\mbox{red}}$, $\,x_s\,$ is chosen at random and $\,\sigma = 1/10\,$ in the renditions depicted here:

[image]

A nice property of the convolution is that $\overline{f}(x)$ inherits the smoothness
of the kernel. One might alternatively define that kernel as a Gauss function. Thus:
$$ \overline{f}(x) =
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-t)^2/\sigma^2} f(t)\,dt
$$
This results in a not so simple expression, but the advantage is that
$\overline{f}(x)$ is truly analytic. I leave this as an exercise to the reader.
Visualization does not differ much from the ones given.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't accept this before. Thank you very much! This has simplified my previous numeical calculations a lot!

Comment: After all these months, it comes as a surprise. But OK, I'm glad you appreciate.