# Modify discontinuous function to compute derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, machine-learning, continuity

I'm creating a machine learning model to beat the house in a competitive game. In this setup, there is a lot of past data on previous games, where each game has: a winner, w (either A or B), gambling odds (x and y for teams A and B), and a probability that team A wins, p, which I compute. The gambling odds are how much reward I get after winning a bet. For example, if team A is projected by the house to have a much better chance of winning, they may set x=1.05, and y=7.5. If I bet \$1 on B and win, I get a net profit of \$7.5-\$1=\$6.5. If I bet \$1 on A or B and lose, then I get a net profit of -\$1. I can also choose to not bet for a net profit of \$0. The gambling odds are always greater than or equal to 1.0. I'm on mobile, so I can't latex this, but here's a drawing of the objective function I'm trying to maximize for each game 
[image: pic]

Since the probability model is a neural network, I need the derivative of f wrt p, but that isn't defined because f is not continuous wrt p. Alternatively, I could just do cross entropy loss on p, but I don't have access to the actual probabilities, just the winner w, and I can't guarantee that the distribution created is therefore good against the house.

Is there a way to modify my objective function that allows me to obtain the desired partial derivative? If not, what else can I do?

Comment: One idea is to smooth the objective function using convolution: {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Differentiation}

Comment: @avs Interesting, how do I decide on a function to convolve with?

Comment: Since you are looking to smooth, I'd go with something infinitely smooth, compactly supported, well-understood (frequently used for smoothing in other areas of mathematics, such as PDE analysis): mollifiers {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier}.

Comment: @avs From the images and article on mollifiers, I'm worried that the derivative will be zero too often, which is a problem because the neural net will need some notion of progress.

Comment: If the concern is being stuck in local minima (which are inherently there, if the convolution reveals them), how about minimizing with simulated annealing?

Comment: @avs Not regular local minima--specifically local minima if the mollified objective is too close to the original function away from would-be vertical lines in the original objective. For example, if the gambling odds say B will win, but A wins, and p=0.1 now, I could improve by increasing p sufficiently, but the gradient will be 0 because the original objective is 0 there, and the mollified objective is also 0 because the mollifier was so close to the identity at that point.

Comment: So, how about simulated annealing?

Comment: @avs I'd rather not resort to that--too slow and unpredictable for me. I might just choose a function that sets the gradient to something positive when the probability is too low and something negative otherwise.

Comment: _To smooth the objective function using convolution_ ? Maybe an answer has been given in [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734096/approximating-piecewise-linear-function) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objective seems to predict how much you would have won *assuming your probability is correct*, which seems a weird choice. You also force it to choose one or the other, which obviously makes things harder to differentiate.

To fix both I would suggest you let the model suggest a strategy, rather than forcing an all or nothing choice. So if the model returns $p$ you choose $A$ with probability $p$ and $B$ with probability $1-p$. This results in the folowing objective function

$$
f(p) = \begin{cases}
p (x-1) + (1-p)(-1) & w = A\\
p (-1) + (1-p) (y-1) & w = B
\end{cases}
$$

which has a simple derivative with respect to $p$.

If you want to be even more adventurous you can also try to make the model return betting amounts $b_A$ and $b_B$ and optimize the objective function

$$
f(b_A, b_B) = \begin{cases}
b_A (x-1) + b_B(-1) & w = A\\
b_A (-1) + b_B(y-1) & w = B
\end{cases}
$$

but perhaps it's best to limit it to $1 per bet.

Comment: I like it, thank you for the simple solution!