# Smooth Logarithm at zero/one with special conditions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, logarithms

As part of a bigger problem it turned out that the function

$$V: \Bbb R \rightarrow [0,\infty ), \,  V(x) := \begin{cases} 0 &:  x \leq 1 \\ \log(x) &: x > 1 \end{cases}$$
would help me alot if it was smooth or rather $C^2$. There would be a way out of this by taking/searching a new function $\varphi: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty) $ instead of $V$ with the following conditions for a $\varepsilon > 0$:

1. $\varphi|_{(-\infty,1-\varepsilon] \cup [1+\varepsilon,\infty)} = V$
2. $\varphi \geq V $
3. $\varphi \in C^2(\Bbb R)$

How can I show the existence of such an $\varphi$?

Comment: Such functions exist, having derivatives of all orders at all points, but they cease to be differentiable as soon as you view them as functions of a complex variable rather than of a real variable.

Comment: are you, substantially, looking for a function to add to $V$ and "round the corner" ?

Comment: A quite analogous problem, with a solution, is found here : __[Approximating piecewise linear function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734096/approximating-piecewise-linear-function)__ .

Comment: Now I've revised my answer and undeleted it. $\qquad$

Comment: See proof of condition 2 in the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of possible approximations.

In particular, the variant
$$\varphi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\log(1+a(x-1+\varepsilon)^6+b(x-1+\varepsilon)^5+c(x-1+\varepsilon)^4),\text{ if }x\in(1-\varepsilon, 1 + \varepsilon)\\[4pt]
V(x), \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}\tag1$$
$$\varphi'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{6a(x-1+\varepsilon)^5+5b(x-1+\varepsilon)^4+4c(x-1+\varepsilon)^3}{1+a(x-1+\varepsilon)^6+b(x-1+\varepsilon)^5+c(x-1+\varepsilon)^4},\text{ if }x\in(1-\varepsilon, 1 + \varepsilon)\\[4pt]
V'(x), \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$\varphi''(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{30a(x-1+\varepsilon)^4+20b(x-1+\varepsilon)^3+12c(x-1+\varepsilon)^2}{1+a(x-1+\varepsilon)^6+b(x-1+\varepsilon)^5+c(x-1+\varepsilon)^4}-\\[4pt]
\dfrac{(6a(x-1+\varepsilon)^5+5b(x-1+\varepsilon)^4+4c(x-1+\varepsilon)^3)^2}{(1+a(x-1+\varepsilon)^6+b(x-1+\varepsilon)^5+c(x-1+\varepsilon)^3)^4},\text{ if }x\in(1-\varepsilon, 1 + \varepsilon)\\[4pt]
V''(x), \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
provides conditions in the point $x=1-\varepsilon.$

Other conditions can be presented in the form of
\begin{cases}
\log(1+64a\varepsilon^6+32b\varepsilon^5+16c\varepsilon^4) = \log(1+\varepsilon)\\[4pt]
\dfrac{192a\varepsilon^5+80b\varepsilon^4+32c\varepsilon^3}{1+64a\varepsilon^6+32b\varepsilon^5+8c\varepsilon^4} = \dfrac1{1+\varepsilon}\\[4pt]
\dfrac{(480a\varepsilon^4+160b\varepsilon^3+48c\varepsilon^2))(1+64a\varepsilon^6+32b\varepsilon^5+16c\varepsilon^4)-(192a\varepsilon^5+80b\varepsilon^3+32c\varepsilon^2)^2}{(1+64a\varepsilon^6+32b\varepsilon^5+16c\varepsilon^4)^2}\\[4pt]
\qquad =-\dfrac1{(1+\varepsilon)^2},
\end{cases}
or
\begin{cases}
64a\varepsilon^5+32b\varepsilon^4+16c\varepsilon^3 = 1\\[4pt]
192a\varepsilon^5+80b\varepsilon^4+32c\varepsilon^3 = 1\\[4pt]
480a\varepsilon^4+160b\varepsilon^3+48c\varepsilon^2= 0,\\
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
a = \dfrac1{32\varepsilon^5}\\[4pt]
b = -\dfrac3{16\varepsilon^4}\\[4pt]
c = \dfrac5{16\varepsilon^3}.
\tag2\end{cases}
Therefore, the approximation has form $(1)$ with the coefficients $(2).$

For $\varepsilon = 0.1$ see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Blog(1%2By)%20%3D%20log(1%2B100000(y%2B0.1)%5E6%2F32%20-30000(y%2B0.1)%5E5%2F16%2B5000(y%2B0.1)%5E4%2F16)%7D,%20y%20in%20(-0.20,%200.20)).

[image: Aproximation plot]

---

**Addition of 09.06.2018**

To prove of the condition $2,$ let us consider the polynomial
$$P_6(y) = ay^6+by^5+cy^4$$
with the coefficients $(2),$ i.e.
$$P_6(y) = \dfrac1{32\varepsilon^5}y^6-\dfrac3{16\varepsilon^4}y^5 +\dfrac5{16\varepsilon^3}y^4
=\dfrac1{32\varepsilon^5}(y^6-6\varepsilon y^5+10\varepsilon^2y^4).$$
Then
$$\varphi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\log(1+P_6(x-1+\varepsilon)),\text{ if }x\in(1-\varepsilon, 1 + \varepsilon)\\[4pt]
V(x), \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Easy to see that
$$P_6(y) = \dfrac1{32\varepsilon^5}y^4\left((y-3\varepsilon)^2+\varepsilon^2\right)\ge0,$$
so condition $2$ is satisfied for $x\le1.$

On the other hand,

$$P_6(2\varepsilon) = \varepsilon,\quad \varphi(1+\varepsilon) = V(1+\varepsilon)$$
and
$$\left(P_6(y) - (y+1-\varepsilon)\right)' = \dfrac1{16\varepsilon^5}\left(3y^5-15\varepsilon y^4 +20\varepsilon^2 y^3-16\varepsilon^5\right) 
= \dfrac1{16\varepsilon^5}\left(y-2\varepsilon\right)^3 (3y^2+3\varepsilon y+2\varepsilon^2)\le0\text{ if } y\in(\varepsilon, 2\varepsilon].$$
These mean that 
$$P_6(y)\ge y+1-\varepsilon, \text{ if } y\in(\varepsilon, 2\varepsilon],$$
so condition $2$ is satisfied for $x\in(1,1+\varepsilon],$

Proved.

Comment: This approach seems to be better adapted to the problem. Your plot suggests that the condition $\varphi \geq V$ is fulfilled. Thank you very much, I will try to verify condition 2. in time.

Comment: @Falrach Condition 2 is important for this task and should be verified. If to reduce the degree of polynomial under the logarithm, this condition doesn't satisfy on the right branch of $V(x).$ So I think that the degree is useful parameter of the solution. At the same time, this approach makes the issue problem really interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a connection polynomial with the following constraints:

- $p(1-\epsilon)=p'(1-\epsilon)=p''(1-\epsilon)=0$,
- $p(1+\epsilon)=\log(1+\epsilon),p'(1+\epsilon)=\dfrac1{1+\epsilon},p''(1+\epsilon)=-\dfrac1{(1+\epsilon)^2}$,

defined over $[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$, and $V$ elsewhere.

As there are six constraints, you will need a quintic polynomial. The equations to determine the coefficients are linear.

There is no a priori guarantee that the polynomial will remain positive in the required range, but I wouldn't be surprised that this occurs naturally.

Comment: That's a good thing. I already thought about that before, and wrote a MATLAB script as well to compute the coefficients in respect to $\varepsilon$. Plotting let me guess $\varphi \geq 0$ should work, $\varphi \geq V$ would be left to prove, but could be done by easy analysis. But all in all this will be my last alternative I want to consider , cause the calculations are horrible and horribly long.

Comment: In fact, the computation looks fairly simple. If you reduce the interval to $[0,1]$, the polynomial $t^3(at^2+bt+c)$ ensures the three left constraints. To obtain the three unkowns, you have an easy $3\times3$ linear system with integer coefficients.

Comment: You are right and what I wrote above is not what I meant. Of course the calculation IS simple, but in my opinion it is not a really elegant way and the terms that occur are horribly long (for this fairly simple steps). But it is a solution with simple computations. Nothing deep as you said.

Comment: @Falrach: they are not.

Comment: This conditions is nesessary. But who can guarantee the issue condition $\varphi \ge V?$

Answer (score 1):

This will describe a function $\varphi$ whose domain is $[0,\infty),$ for which $\varphi(x)$ is equal to $0$ if $0 \le x \le 1-\varepsilon,$ equal to $\log x$ it $1-\varepsilon\le x,$ and is in $C^\infty,$ i.e. it has continuous derivatives of all orders at every point.

However, I am not yet entirely happy with it, since I would like to see it as convex, i.e. concave upward, on the interval whose endpoints are $1\pm\varepsilon.$ And I suspect that can be done without a very large amount of additional work.

Start with this function: 
$g_1(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for } x\le 0, \\ e^{-1/x} & \text{for } x>0. \end{cases}$
 This is obviously $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb R\smallsetminus \{0\}.$ That it has continuous derivatives of all orders at $0$ takes some work to show. I seem to recall a proof by induction on the order of the derivative, after a substitution, but I don't remember the details.

Let $g_2(x) = g_1(x)g_1(a-x)$ for some $a>0.$ This is a $C^\infty$ function that is positive for $0<x<a$ and $0$ for $x$ elsewhere.

Then let $\displaystyle g_3(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \left. \int_0^x g_2(u)\,du \right/\!\!\int_0^a g_2(u)\,du & \text{for } x\ge 0, \\[6pt] 0 & \text{for } x<0. \end{cases}$ 
 This is a $C^\infty$ function that is equal to $0$ for $x\le0,$ equal to $1$ for $x\ge a,$ and between $0$ and $1$ for $0<x<a.$

For some $b>2a,$ let $g_4(x) = g_3(x) g_3(b-x).$ Then $g_4(x)$ is equal to $0$ for $x\le0$ or $x\ge b,$ equal to $1$ for $a\le x\le b-a,$ and between $0$ and $1$ for $0<x<a$ or $b-a<x<b.$

Let $g_5(x) = g_4(x-(1-\varepsilon)),$ with $a=\varepsilon/2$ and $b = 2\varepsilon.$ Then $g_5$ is a $C^\infty$ function equal to $0$ for $x\le0$ or $x\ge2\varepsilon,$ equal to $1$ for $\varepsilon/2\le x\le 3\varepsilon/2\le 2\varepsilon,$ and between $0$ and $1$ in the two intervals between.

Let $g_6(x) = 1 - g_5(x).$

Next, let $\varphi(x) = V(x) g_6(x).$

Comment: And where is the final formulas which relate with a logarithmic function?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov : The last line says $\varphi(x) = V(x) g_6(x).$ And $V(x)$ is defined in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try a **convolution** with *a function of small width and great height*
(: Richard P. Feynman in *Space-Time Approach to Quantum Electrodynamics* ).
Name this function $\delta(x)$ (not quite by coincidence). The simplest one is this:
$$
\delta(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{for} & x \le \epsilon \\
1/(2\epsilon) & \mbox{for} & -\epsilon \le x \le +\epsilon \\
0 & \mbox{for} & x \ge +\epsilon
\end{cases}
$$
The geometry of $\,\delta(x)\,$ is a rectangle with height $1/(2\epsilon)$ and width $2\epsilon$ ,
resulting in an area $1$, thus establishing that the function $\,\delta(x)\,$ is normed.
Now define:
$$ \overline{V}(x) = 
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x-t)\,V(t)\,dt
= \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} V(t)\,dt
$$
With $\,\int \ln(t)\,dt = t\ln(t)-t$ . Then we have
for $\,x \le 1-\epsilon$ :
$$
\overline{V}(x) = \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} 0 \,dt = 0
$$
for $\,1-\epsilon \le x \le 1+\epsilon$ :
$$
\overline{V}(x) =
\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{x-\epsilon}^1 0 \,dt + \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_1^{x+\epsilon}\left[t\ln(t)-t\right]dt =
\left[(x+\epsilon)\ln(x+\epsilon)-(x+\epsilon)+1\right]/(2\epsilon)
$$
for $\,x \ge 1+\epsilon$ :
$$
\overline{V}(x) = \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon}\left[t\ln(t)-t\right]dt =
\left[(x+\epsilon)\ln(x+\epsilon)-(x-\epsilon)\ln(x-\epsilon)\right]/(2\epsilon)-1
$$
Sketch of the original $\,V(x)\,$ and its smoothed approximation $\,\color{red}{\overline{V}(x)}$ :

[image]
In this picture `eps` $\epsilon\,$ and viewport are defined as:

```
  eps : double = 1;
  xmin := -2; xmax := 5;
  ymin := -0.1; ymax := 2.9;
```

Comment: This seems to smoothen $V$ about one degree, but $\overline{V}$ violates condition 1. and 2. I think. I am not even sure if $\overline{V}$ is twice differentiable. Wasn't this your attempt?

Comment: $\overline{V}$ can be smoothed about infinitely many degrees e.g. by choosing a Gaussian instead of a rectangle - though I don't know if there is a closed form for the integrals in that case. Condition 2. can be fulfilled by adding a small number to $\overline{V}(x)$. But still then condition 1. cannot be fulfilled and the approximation becomes even worse in that respect. I cannot judge how serious these flaws are for your purpose, but in case they are: you don't have to accept my answer anyway. Then consider my attempt as a (maybe indeed somewhat too) approximate solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok. I was not sure about wether you are aware of the conditions. I know that convolution is often used to smoothen functions. And though this way may does not fit my purpose, it is is good to see something in this direction. I've learned something and that's the main thing. I think, there are several problems where this can be helpful and something like condition 2. is not necessary.